# Creating Json Object Template From Objects Of Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have one JSON which looks something like this

```
{  
   "uniqueId":"junk",
   "buildingId":"123",
   "famousFor":[  
      {  
         "famousForId":"asd",
         "name":"Gaming",
         "activeState":true
      }
   ],
   "openHours":[  
      {  
         "day":"Sunday",
         "timingsFrom":{  
            "time":"11:00",
            "meridian":"AM"
         },
         "timingsTo":{  
            "time":"11:59",
            "meridian":"PM"
         }
      }
   ],
   "uploadedImages":{  
      "coverPhoto":[  
         {  
            "imageUrl":"http://google.com/images/a123a.png",
            "activeState":false
         }
      ],
      "profilePhoto":[  
         {  
            "imageUrl":"http://google.com/images/a123a.png, 
                        "            activeState":false
         }
      ]
   },
   "fDescriptions":[  
      {  
         "fMapUrl":"http://google.com/images/a123a.png",
         "tag":"1"
      }
   ],
   "Outlets":[  
      {  
         "outletName":"Halo",
         "floorNumber":1,
         "category":"Gaming"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now the thing is I have to create one GET API which essentially will provide me the same template with empty value. While returning the Object it's sending me the null value. How can I standardized the template that looks the same. My Object looks something like this.

```
public class EssentialDetails {

    @NotBlank(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)
    @Valid
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+$",message="DP ID Must be Number")
    String dpId;
    @Id @NotBlank(message= ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)
    @Valid
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+$",message="Must Be Combination of Number and Letters")
    String tpId;
    @NotNull(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)   @Valid
    List<FamousFor> famousFor;
    @NotNull(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)  @Valid
    List<OpenHours> openHours;
    @NotNull(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)  @Valid
    Pictures uploadedImages;
    @NotNull(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD) @Valid
    List<FloorDescription> floorDescriptions;
    @NotNull(message=ApplicationUtil.MISSING_FIELD)  @Valid
    List<Outlets> mallOutlets;

}
```

How can I pass the empty template with every field present within the template? I'm using java 8 and spring boot 2.0.6.

Comment: so you require empty key for those values whoes object is not present?

Comment: @KOTIOS very true, i need that key to be present however value can be null or empty

Comment: So you just need each field to be an empty string instead or null right? if a new instance of the model is returned.

Comment: @Code_Is_Law i need empty string, i know if i would initialize that Object and return it will automatically return null value, however even if i initialized the nested objects not all the nested attributes are being populated.it's just returns empty list

Answer (score 0):

Incase of empty or null or some valid values below annotation can be used above property of your model

```
@JsonInclude(ALWAYS)
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to be a proper solution and didn't worked

Comment: can u please tell me if this tag generated the empty tag?, if there is more validating annotation along with this tags then it will be depending if that can be generated or not

Comment: it didn't generated the empty tag as well, however i found the way to solve this using java 8 feature,
a sample to this one is inscriber below
`return ObjectConverter.convertSingleResource(essentialDetails, essentialDetails1 -> {
           EssentialDetailsDTO essentialDetailsDTO = new EssentialDetailsDTO();
            essentialDetailsDTO.setDpId(essentialDetails1.getDpId());
            essentialDetailsDTO.setTpId(essentialDetails1.getTpId());
            `